# unable to update softwate in ubunutu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, updates

After checking ubuntu update button showing these following errors on given below:

```
unable to download updates you don't have permission to install software ubuntu
```

My ubuntu version is: `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`

Comment: `you don't have permission to install software ubuntu` That says alot, you have to grant yourself a superuser privilege to update.

Comment: Hi Sabbir!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please be more specific about the method you are attempting to use to update Ubuntu?  By default, the user that was specified during the install is an administrative user, so the GUI update method will work. (a.k.a. "Software Updates") But if you are doing this from a command line then you will need to preface the command with `sudo` to perform something *as root*.

Comment: thanks, @tu-ReinstateMonica-dorduh will try this hopefully it will be works

Answer (score 0):

See the date and time section, type date on the terminal, it will give you the date set by your computer. If sometimes the date is incorrectly set by the automatic date and time function then this issue may occur, which occurred to me a while back.

Also you need to run sudo apt-get function for updating, upgrading and downloading other libraries. Check if you have done that also.